# Determine if a number is a primitive root

Tags: elementary-number-theory, primitive-roots

Let $p$ be an odd prime, let $g$ be a primitive root of $p$. Prove $-g$ is a primitive root of $p$ if and only if 
$$p\equiv1\pmod{4}$$
Hint: express $-g$ as $g^{k}$, then use property 6 ... verify $$gcd((p+1)/2,p-1) = gcd((p-1)/2,((p-1)/2)-1)$$
Unfortunately I am not entirely sure what property 6 is, but I believe it is:
"If $g$ is a primitive root of $p$, then $g^k$ is a primitive root of $p$ if and only if $gcd(ϕ(p),k)=1$
Can anyone confirm that this is the property I need for this proof?
So far I have:
Let $g$ be a primitive root of an odd prime $p$. Because $g$ is a primitive root all other equivalence classes $mod(p)$ can be expressed as a power of $g$. Therefore there is some integer $k$ such that $-g\equiv g^k$.

From here I'm not sure how to continue or even what the rest of the hint is suggesting.

Comment: Who gave that hint? How come you're not sure what "property 6" is??

Comment: My professor gave the hint. I'm not sure what property 6 is because he doesn't specify what properties he's referring to, and I can't find a list of 6+ properties in my notes or on any of the handouts i have. I messaged a classmate, but he never responded so that leaves me in a bit of a pickle

Comment: What about asking your prof. ...?? Could it be that $\;-1\;$ is a quadratic residue modulo a prime $\;p\;$ iff $\;p=-1\pmod 4\;$ ?\

Comment: Well it's 4am here so I don't imagine he would be very responsive lol If I can't figure this out I plan to ask him in the morning

Comment: Yes, do that....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $g$ is a primitive root, then $$g^{p-1}\equiv_p1\iff (g^{\frac{p-1}{2}}-1)(g^{\frac{p-1}{2}}+1)\equiv_p 0$$ Since $g$ is a primitive root $g^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\not\equiv_p 1$, we must have $$g^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\equiv_p -1$$

Therefore $(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}g^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\equiv_p (-g)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\equiv_p (-1)^{\frac{p+1}{2}}$, so $-g$ is a primitive root $\iff p\equiv_4 1$.

Comment: $p \equiv 1 mod(4)$ implies that $\frac{p-1}2$ is even right?

Comment: That's right. But it also implies that $(-g)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\equiv_p -1$, which means that $-g$ is a primitive root.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that $(-1)^\frac{p-1}2 = 1$ since $\frac{p-1}2$ is even?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Hm, well then why is $(−1)^\frac{p−1}2 g^\frac{p−1}2 ≡(−g)^\frac{p−1}2 mod(p)$ valid?

Comment: Sorry if that's a dumb question I just have a hard time seeing the relationships in congruences

Comment: Do you agree that $(-1)^2 3^2=(-3)^2$? That's the same idea.

Comment: ohhh i see what you mean, thanks

Answer (score 2):

More generally ord$_pa=d\implies$ ord $_p(a^k)=\dfrac d{(k,d)}$ ([Proof](http://archive.org/details/NumberTheory_862) @Page#95)

Using [Prove that $a^{(p-1)/2} \equiv 1$ (mod p) and $a^{(p-1)/2} \equiv -1$ (mod p)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/502089/prove-that-ap-1-2-equiv-1-mod-p-and-ap-1-2-equiv-1-mod-p),

$$\displaystyle -g\equiv g^{\frac{p-1}2+1}\pmod p$$

Now if $d$ divides both $\dfrac{p+1}2, p-1$

$d$ must divide $2\cdot\dfrac{p+1}2-(p-1)=2$

$\implies\left(\dfrac{p+1}2, p-1\right)=1$ iff $\dfrac{p+1}2$ is odd as $p-1$ is even

$\dfrac{p+1}2=2n+1$(say)$\implies p=4n+1\equiv1\pmod4$

Comment: do you mean g^(((p-1)/2))+1) or g^((p-1)/2)+1? The formatting on this site is hard to deal with lol

Comment: @JakeRyan34, Have you understood uptil then?

Comment: I think so. I'm working my way through that other thread and comparing it to this problem.

Comment: @JakeRyan34, The exponent is $$1+\dfrac{(p-1)}2$$

Comment: In that case I don't understand haha. Whose answer should I be looking at on that thread?

Comment: From the way I'm understanding this, by Fermat's Little Theorem, we know that $g^{p-1} \equiv 1 mod(p)$. So, $0 \equiv g^{p-1}-1 \equiv (g^{(p-1)/2}-1)(g^{(p-1)/2}+1) mod(p)$. And since p is prime, $g^{(p-1)/2} \equiv 1$ or $-1 mod(p)$

Comment: But I'm not seeing how you represented $-g$ as $g^{\frac{p-1}2+1}$

Comment: @JakeRyan34, What is the order of $g\pmod p?$

Comment: It's $p-1$ right?

Comment: @JakeRyan34, Then $$g^{(p-1)/2}\not\equiv1\pmod p$$ right?

Comment: That I'm not convinced about. To consider a specific example, take $p=5$ with $g=2$ as a primitive root. Then $2^{\frac{5-1}2} \equiv 1 mod(5)$ => $4 \equiv 1 mod(5)$ doesn't hold right?

Comment: Oh never mind you edited that. I see your point now

Comment: I'm convinced that you're right but how did you derive that exponent?